# How to avoid type argument erasure

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

My code uses Scala and the Breeze linear algebra library. I have objects of types `DenseVector[Double]`, `DenseVector[Int]`, etc... where `DenseVector` is an array-like container with dedicated methods for numerical computations. I sometimes need to use pattern matching against the contained type. Type-erasure forced me to introduce a trait and "wrapping" case classes:

```
sealed trait DenseVectorRoot
case class DenseVectorReal(val data: DenseVector[Real]) extends DenseVectorRoot
case class DenseVectorMatrixReal(val data: DenseVector[DenseMatrix[Real]]) extends DenseVectorRoot
```

(Where `Real` is just an alias for `Double`).

Pattern matching would look like:

```
def print(data: DenseVectorRoot) =
  data match {
    case DenseVectorMatrixReal(_) => println("Contains real matrices")
    case DenseVectorReal(_) => println("Contains real scalars")
  }
```

I would like to get rid of the `DenseVectorRoot` trait. I attempted this:

```
def print2(data: DenseVector[_ <: Any]) =
  data match {
    case _: DenseVector[Double] => println("Contains real matrices")
    case _: DenseVector[Int] => println("Contains real scalars")
  }
```

But the type arguments get erased.

How should I modify `print2` using ClassTags so that pattern matching works ? For example by printing the correct output in the following code:

```
val v0 = DenseVector(1.2, 1.5, 1.6)
val v1 = DenseVector(3, 4, 5)

val a = Array(v0, v1)
a.map(print2)
```

**EDIT**

The main reason why I need to manage an `Array` with varying containers is that my code need to manage various types of data (for example, parsing input would be different for a `DenseVector[Real]` and for a `DenseVector[Matrix[Real]]`). My current design is to store everything in an `Array[DenseVectorRoot]`, and then process the data using high-order functions like `.map()`. Each of this function will, on an element-to-element basis, pattern-match to know if the data is a `DenseVectorReal` or a `DenseVectorMatrixReal`, and act accordingly.

That might not be the optimal design to solve my problem, but I do not know at compile time what types of data are provided by a user. I would be happy to know any better design !

Comment: Why trying to print such `DenseVector` out the `DenseVectorReal` or `DenseVectorMatrixReal` context (which allow to have know type for `data`) ?

Comment: Printing is just a basic example. I actually need to perform different numerical computations according to the type argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `TypeTag`

You can request that the compiler infers the parameter type, and generates a [`TypeTag`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for you.
You can then use the `TypeTag` to check for a certain type, or you can `print` it for debugging purposes.

### Example Code

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def printType[A: TypeTag](a: List[A]): Unit = 
  println(if(typeTag[A] == typeTag[Double]) "Double" else "other")

printType(List(1.0))
printType(List(1))
```

### Output

```
>Double
>other
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing is better done with type classes:

```
  trait DenseContent[T] {
    def compute(v: DenseVector[T]): String
  }
  object DenseContent {
    implicit object _Real extends DenseContent[Real] {
      def compute(v: DenseVector[Real]) = "real"
    }
    implicit object _Int extends DenseContent[Int] {
      def compute(v: DenseVector[Int]) = "int"
    }
    // etc ...
  }

  def print2[T : DenseContent](data: DenseVector[T]) = println(
     implicitly[DenseContent[T]].compute(data)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, architecturing like this will allow me to centralize more behaviours. New types will be added more easily too.

Comment: I tried it in the example given at the end of the post, and got two errors:

"could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type p06sandbox.TypeClasses.DenseContent[T]"

and

"value compute is not a member of p06sandbox.TypeClasses.DenseContent[T]"

Comment: Well, the snippet I quoted in the answer compiles and works, if pasted  into repl literally (I just did `class DenseVector[T]` and `type Real = Double` before it, and `print2(new DenseVector[Int])` after to test). So, you must be doing something differently. Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Maybe I missed something... Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/zB7Ad1e4

Comment: Your code works fine for me ... (I just had to define `class DenseVector[T]` as before, because I don't have breeze, but that isn't relevant).

Comment: Could you pastebin your working code ? It will be easier to spot the error for me...

Comment: Oh, wait ... `a.map(print2)` won't work like that, because the type of `a` is `Array[DenseVector[_ >: Int with Double <: AnyVal]]`, so the `T` is neither `Int` nor `Double`, but this weird concoction. You should not mix variables of different types in arrays ...

Comment: Yes, this is why I use an `Array[DenseVectorRoot]` in my current code and then pattern-match. I edited my post to detail this.

Comment: Just add `compute` to `DenseVectorRoot` then, and simply `.map(_.compute)`  instead of pattern matching. This is the same idea as type classes, but without implicits.